# Paperclip with multiple server instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip in RoR , and I am having some troubles when showing the images. Some times some images are shown and some other times thy are not. Does anybody has experienced something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using local paths to save the images, paperclip will save them on the server processing the request.

Next requests to show the image will work if they are received on the same server where it was saved, or will fail if the request is processed by another server.

To avoid that you should be using a common storage, for example s3.